# Assign Values to Drop-Down Menus in PayPal Third-Party Carts

Tags: drop-down-menu, paypal

I am trying to implement a PayPal cart on a third-party site. Customers are first asked to select a product ("Product") from a drop-down menu and then, optionally, to enter a specific amount ("Additional Costs") into a text field. Both values should finally be sent to PayPal upon submitting.

While everything works fine with two text fields, where `amount_1` and `amount_2` are clearly defined, I struggle with assigning different values (/amounts, say 10.00 and 5.00) to the options of the drop down and to make the value of the selected option my value `amount_1`. Here is the code I figured out so far:

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="whatever@gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Product">
  <input type="hidden" name="on0_1" value="Product">
  <select name="os0_1">
    <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
  </select>

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Additional Costs">
  <input type="text" name="amount_2" value="0.00">GBP
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

`option_select` and `option_amount` do not seem to work with this kind of form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the select box that is used to select the product `amount_1`:

```
<select name="os0_1">
    <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
</select>
```

What you need to do is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Product" id="item_name_1">
<select name="amount_1" onchange="changeProductName()" id="amount_1">
    <option value="5.00">Product that is a fiver</option>
    <option value="10.00">Product that is a tenner</option>
</select>

<script>
    function changeProductName() {
        var e = document.getElementById('amount_1');
        var h = document.getElementById('item_name_1');

        h.value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
```

That will change the `item_name_1` to the friendly value of the price option.